# Adding new elements to a Collection instead of transforming them?

Tags: java, collections, guava

Using Guava, is it possible to add new items to a Collection instaed of only transforming a Collection?

Imagine e.g. I have

```
Set<Integer> numbers = Sets.newHashSet(1,2,3);
```

Now, in addition to the already present numbers, also the double and triple of each number shall be included, therefore 2,4,6 as well as 3,6,9.

Is there something in Guava like

```
addToSet(numbers, <a function returning a List of values for each element in numbers>)
```

?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: No, there isn't, but it's not hard to build out of what's already provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`transformAndConcat`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v14.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.html) does the job, allows returning more than one element, though only one element was passed to the transform function.

Answer (score 3):

Why would something like [Set.addAll(Collection c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) not suffice?

```
Set<Integer> numbers = Sets.newHashSet(1,2,3);
numbers.addAll(setReturningFunction());
```

Comment: hmm, you are probably right, setReturningFunction could simply the a Guava Function retuning the additional items. Still wondering if that's also somehow included in Guava, because by using your way, I once have to write numbers for numbers.addAll and once for teling Guava where to apply the Function. Would it be directly integrated into Guava, I could use the FluentIterable, so one would only have to write numbers once ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Decorate the Set (could use a ForwardingSet) and then override the add method to add the additional items into the backing delegate.